# Why doesn't ld find some symbols from shared libs

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have the following files:

**file liba.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {printf("foo\n"); }
void bar() {printf("bar\n"); }
```

**file libb.c**

```
void foo();
void abc() { foo(); }
```

**main.c**

```
void abc();
void foo();
void bar();

int main()
{
   abc();
   foo();
   bar();
}
```

I am compiling the files as follows:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o liba.so liba.c
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-rpath,. -Wl,--no-undefined -o libb.so libb.c liba.so
gcc -Wl,-rpath,. main.c libb.so
```

Now the linker reports an error when linking the executable:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4De1Xu.o: undefined reference to symbol 'bar'  
./liba.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now the question is: Why doesn't the linker find the symbol *bar*? *main.c* is linked against *libb.so* which in turn has been linked against *liba.so* and *liba.so* does have the symbol *bar*. Also *main.c* uses symbol *foo* and this also resides in *liba.so* and this is found during linking.

So both symbols, *foo* and *bar*, are defined in *liba.so* but only *foo* is found during linking. Why?

It looks like only symbols from *liba.so* are found that are used in *libb.so*. But why is this the case?

Comment: without further analysis, last line should read `gcc -L. -Wl,-rpath,. -lb main.c`

Comment: This is even worse as it reports abc, foo and bar as undefined since main.c is listed after -lb. Moving -lb after main.c results in the same error message as my invocation above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with symbol `bar` not beeing included in the export table of *libb.so* but only in *liba.so*. Why don't you link main.c also against *liba.so*?
Else, declaring `void bar();` in *libb.c* should help..

Comment: Yes, that would fix the linker error, but I want to know why it is the way it is.

Comment: As i wrote, i think the symbol void bar() is not exported by module libb.so...  and there just no relation from main.c to liba.so..

Comment: There is a relation from libb.so to liba.so since the symbol foo is resolved during linking. So ld does know liba.so while linking and it does resolve symbols from it (symbol foo). Now since it knows liba.so and it knows its symbols (e.g. symbol foo), then why doesn't it also resolve symbol bar?